# How to drag a DIV so its width and height are negative values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm a bit stumped here. I am developing a feedback utility that will allow the user to "draw" boxes on a web page to highlight problem areas. Right now I have an overlay DIV that fills the screen and jQuery allows you to draw red outlined DIVs by clicking and dragging.

Here is the JS:

```
{
    var $feedbackOverlay = jQuery('#feedbackOverlay');
    var $original = { top: 0, left:0 };
    $feedbackOverlay.bind('mousedown', function (e)
    {
        jQuery('<div id="currentHighlight"></div>')
            .css('width', '1px')
            .css('height', '1px')
            .css('border', 'solid 3px #ff0000')
            .css('border-radius', '5px')
            .css('position', 'absolute')
            .css('left', e.pageX)
            .css('top', e.pageY)
            .css('z-index', '8000001')
            .appendTo('body');

        $original = { top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX };
    });
    $feedbackOverlay.bind('mousemove', function (e)
    {
        var $currentHighlight = jQuery('#currentHighlight');
        if ($currentHighlight.length > 0)
        {
            var $pos = { top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX };

            if($pos.top < $original.top) $currentHighlight.css('top', $pos.top);
            if ($pos.left < $original.left) $currentHighlight.css('left', $pos.left);

            $currentHighlight.height(Math.abs($pos.top - $original.top));
            $currentHighlight.width(Math.abs($pos.left - $original.left));
        }
    });
    $feedbackOverlay.bind('mouseup', function (e)
    {
        var $currentHighlight = jQuery('#currentHighlight');
        $currentHighlight.removeAttr('id');
    });
    var $feedbackInstructions = jQuery('#feedbackInstructions');
    $feedbackInstructions.fadeIn(1000, function ()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $feedbackInstructions.fadeOut(1000);
        }, 3000);
    });

    $feedbackOverlay.height(jQuery(document).height());
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle for the above:

http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/RSYTq/

The problem is that I can't drag the boxes up or left. The first click puts the top left corner where the mouse clicked. After that subsequent dragging will change the width of the box. Letting go of the mouse completes the box and you may then start drawing another one. If you try to drag the DIV left or up while drawing it's width will remain at 0 but won't go negative.

Comment: Well shiver me timbers... I'm building something similar.  :-)

Comment: @Larsenal I plan on making it a jQuery plugin. I'm aiming for a more simplistic version of the Google Feedback tool. I couldn't find anything like it.

Comment: If or when you have it up on GitHub, I'd love to follow the project.

Comment: @Larsenal, I will have it up on Google Code after I iron out a few starting bugs. I will update this question with it when I do :) I'd love to collaborate.

Comment: Check out my answer with working solution

Comment: @Diodeus, thanks for editing my grammar. I am embarrassed to have made such an oversight!

Comment: @Larsenal, I got the work in progress up on Google Project Hosting. If you're still interested in following or collaborating then check it out: https://code.google.com/p/sendfeedback/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RSYTq/34/

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't expect a fully working solution. Thanks for the extra effort Sammich.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will get you closer to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/RSYTq/18/

Doesn't quite handle move up and to the left and then switching to moving down and to the right quite right yet but it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing a a negative width - these are not coorindinates. You need to reposition and recalculate the corner positions relative to the corner that's not being moved.

Comment: Right, I'm just not sure how to go about "recalculating". I wondered if I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: You go from moving the bottom-right corner to moving the upper-left while dynamically adjusting the width.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to check if the click origin (x,y) is > than the current mouse position, and then swap which one you use for the CSS top-left.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to track the original start point somewhere (variables, data attributes on `#currentHighlight`, wherever you want), and check for width or height < 0. When so, set the `#currentHighlight` `left`/`top` CSS to be offset by `original + (e.pageX - $currentHighlight.position().left)` (for example). Then set the #currentHighlight width/height to the same difference (but positive: `(e.pageX - $currentHighlight.position().left) * -1`).